# How to recover a DB with a missing .mdf file?

Tags: sql-server

I have a DB and when I detach it I cannot find its `.mdf` file. I only have `.ndf` and `.ldf` files in my `DATA` folder. Also, I do not have backup file...

- How to recover my DB?
- Can I do something without the `.mdf` file?

P.S. On this server, I have more DBs and most them have `.mdf` files. Only a few are missing their `.mdf` files. Why is that?

Comment: On what storage are your DB's?

Comment: Why are you detaching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Have you done a full search on all the drives attached to the SQL Server?  Not just where you expect the files to be, but anywhere on the drive?

It is also possible that they were connected via UNC path (`\\servername\sharename`), have you looked for them there?

If you cannot find the primary file and do not have backups, there isn't anything we can do to help you.  My guess is that either the MDF files are not where you expected them to be, are not named as you expected them to be, or got deleted after you detached the database.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, you don't have to have an MDF file. Your database and log files can be named any extension - MP3, PDF, ZIP, you name it. (Sometimes I play terrible jokes on my coworkers.)

If you want to check the file names before you detach the databases, run this query in the database you want to examine:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

You can also right-click on the database in SSMS and click Properties, then look at the files from there.